# Heroku deploy is failing

Tags: heroku

I've created a react application and it is working fine in my localhost:3000.But it is failing while I try to deploy it to Heroku. 
the error I reveived:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-wave-46792.herokuapp.com request_id=bcf25382-90d2-4d27-a4ff-423bd990c864 fwd="103.242.197.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

my `package.json` scripts looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
  }
```

my server.js looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your
question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four
spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: That doesn't look like a _deploy_ error, but rather a runtime error. Are there any other messages before or after it in the logs that give more information?

Comment: Yes, please insert your code in text, not in a image. And please show us the logs during the deploy.